# Libdevice not found Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run tensorflow using my GPU and have followed the instructions at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). After running the commands in Step 6, I get the proper output.

Then, when I try to run an actual model I am trying to build, I get the following error.

```
2023-01-06 18:39:14.692537: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_helper.cc:56] Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice. This may result in compilation or runtime failures, if the program we try to run uses routines from libdevice.
Searched for CUDA in the following directories:
  ./cuda_sdk_lib
  /usr/local/cuda-11.2
  /usr/local/cuda
  .
You can choose the search directory by setting xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir in HloModule's DebugOptions.  For most apps, setting the environment variable XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/path/to/cuda will work.
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693094: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:326] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693196: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_compilation_cache.cc:477] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693275: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:446 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.704458: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:326] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.704603: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:446 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_Main.py", line 42, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_Main.py", line 27, in main
    model.train()
  File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_V5.py", line 99, in train
    history = self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size = batchSize, epochs = epochs)
  File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'StatefulPartitionedCall_10' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_Main.py", line 42, in <module>
      main(sys.argv[1:])
    File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_Main.py", line 27, in main
      model.train()
    File "/home/jerry/Woodburn/Woodburn_Model/model/main/Model_V5.py", line 99, in train
      history = self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size = batchSize, epochs = epochs)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1027, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 527, in minimize
      self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1140, in apply_gradients
      return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 634, in apply_gradients
      iteration = self._internal_apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1166, in _internal_apply_gradients
      return tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1216, in _distributed_apply_gradients_fn
      distribution.extended.update(
    File "/home/jerry/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall_10'
libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
         [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_10}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_8591]
```

After doing some research, it appears that the relevant errors are the following:

```
2023-01-06 18:39:14.692537: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_helper.cc:56] Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice. This may result in compilation or runtime failures, if the program we try to run uses routines from libdevice.
Searched for CUDA in the following directories:
  ./cuda_sdk_lib
  /usr/local/cuda-11.2
  /usr/local/cuda
  .
You can choose the search directory by setting xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir in HloModule's DebugOptions.  For most apps, setting the environment variable XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/path/to/cuda will work.
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693094: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:326] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693196: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_compilation_cache.cc:477] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
2023-01-06 18:39:14.693275: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:446 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.704458: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:326] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-01-06 18:39:14.704603: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:446 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

For context, this is running in Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.9. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I ran into this issue after updating tensorflow. Running `conda install tensorflow==2.10.*` was enough to "solve" it for me.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that installing `TensorFlow 2.10` resolved this issue. Could you please help us to know the earlier `Tensorflow version` which was showing the above error?

Comment: I had the same issue and downgrading to TF 2.10 fixed it for me as well.

Comment: I had a similar issue only on one of our systems, while the code was working well on our other Windows or Linux systems. Downgrading from 2.11 to 2.10 resolved the issue for the problematic system.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed `Cudatoolkit` through `Conda`, the problem can be fixed by setting the `XLA_FLAGS` with `export XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CONDA_PREFIX`. You can set the env variable everytime you activate the environment, following this: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux